# MS-Access 2013 adding text to current date/time control source

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a footer in MS-Access 2013 that will display the text "Created by Steve Smith" and then next to that display the current time by using the =Now() feature.   My question is can you enter the text "Created by..." in the same text box as =Now()?  When I try this I immediately get an error: Invalid Control Property: Control Source."  I've looked in the control source options but I don't see an option to enter any text in the box, you have to select a control source.  I know I can align another label to the left of the text box to get the look I am going for, but I figured I would ask if it was possible to put everything in the dedicated label box.

[Screenshot of Text box next to label box to make the appearance I am going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVf5k.png)

[Step I thought I could perform to get the result of "Created by Steve Smith on (current date and time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR023.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a close look at the auto-generated "Page x of y" textbox, and use the same technique. Build a valid expression that starts with `=` and concatenates strings / function results:

```
="Created by Steve Smith " & Now()
```

Comment: Ahh!  Good point, I wish I had through of that.  Thank you for the help!